# How to open sapisvr.exe in c# from application

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to open speech recognition in windows

```
Process.Start("sapisvr.exe");
```

But not work.

Comment: Where is this exe? Can you try to write it's full path?

Answer (score 0):

U should path the full path of `"sapisvr.exe"` to the `Process.Start(string path)` method.
By default if u dont pass the full path, it starts searching the '.exe' file in current folder(where ur program's exe file is).
For example, use it like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:/FolderName/sapisvr.exe");
```

NOTE: Don't forget to check if the file exist by this:

```
var filename = @"C:/FolderName/sapisvr.exe"
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    Process.Start(filename);
}
```